# Automatically Detect Websocket Path (Firebase)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Example URL = https://westgate-production-4cb87.firebaseapp.com/super-contests/weekly-card/embed

I've written the code needed to get this to work with the current deployed websocket URL and successfully scrape the data on this page -

```
wss://s-usc1c-nss-276.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=westgate-production-4cb87
```

However, it seems that every so often the number in the subdomain will change (in this example - 276). I can obviously manually figure out what the new URL is using the Network tab in Dev Tools, but I was wondering if there was a Python code snippet or some approach where I can programatically detect what websockets are opening so that I can capture the wss:// URL and then pass it into the rest of my code that works correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using an undocumented way to access the Firebase Realtime Database.

That first part of the URL is the server that your client is connecting to to access the data, and is actually determined by the first request(s) when the connection is established. But as said, this knowledge is not documented and can thus change at any time without notice.

I'd recommend using either the Python SDK, the REST API, or the REST Streaming API to access the database, as all of those are properly documented.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank. That's correct - it's an undocumented way since it's not my Firebase app and I am attempting to scrape the webpage without using Selenium and just connecting to the websocket which I have working fine once I manually check the wss:// URL in Chrome's DevTools. I appreciate the answer though thank you very much.